# Spark a connection with GAE datastore and phonegap

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-datastore

I have got the local datastore running and I can add entities etc. Everything is working well but I want to know how do I store it to the online datastore in Google App Engine?

Do I just deploy it? or Is there some other to way to make the connection to this online database. I have a GAE application set up already. I'm using Eclipse with Java.

One more question in regarding to phonegap do I need to create a web application or just a normal android application in Eclipse because if its an android application I'm not sure how I can run it as web app if I'm using the datastore in GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy your app to App Engine, your code will actually be running inside the data center. It will have access to the real Datastore. When you run devserver, it's not the real App Engine runtime, and the Datastore on devserver is not the real Datastore. So, yes, deploy it.

As far as phonegap, it's a library for taking HTML+CSS+JS web apps and converting them to phone apps. It has limitations and conditions and I would learn more about how it works before getting too locked in.

If you write your app's front-end in HTML+CSS+JS and your [Endpoints API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) runs in App Engine, you can [use JS client library API calls to your Endpoints API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js) which, running its code on App Engine, will have access to the Datastore.